# I wonder how you'd feel watching the longest continuous play recorded?

Tags: wh-questions

My first question:

Is sentence 2 a more formal expression while senteance 1 is an informal expression because the word `about` is dropped?

Could we say the sentence 1 has the same meaning as the sentence 2?

**Sentence1.**

> I wonder `how` you'd feel watching the longest continuous play recorded.

**Sentence2.**

> I wonder `how` you'd feel `about` watching the longest continuous play recorded.

My second question:

What is the difference between these four sentences which are a kind of mixture of how, what and about.

**Sentence3.**

> I wonder `what` you'd feel watching the longest continuous play recorded.

**Sentence4.**

> I wonder `what` you'd feel `about` watching the longest continuous play recorded.

Comment: There is no difference in formality - changing _you'd_ to _you would_ would make the sentences more formal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I wonder HOW you'd feel watching the longest continuous play recorded.
2. I wonder HOW you'd feel ABOUT watching the longest continuous play recorded.
3. I wonder WHAT you'd feel watching the longest continuous play recorded.
4. I wonder WHAT you'd feel ABOUT watching the longest continuous play recorded.

First, I think that in the sense intended, none of these sentences are questions. They therefore require a period at the end, not a question mark.

Secondly, we may all understand these sentences differently. But I would understand #1 to refer to my feelings while watching the recording, and #2 to refer to my feelings while deciding whether to watch. For example, if I knew that the film would embarrass me, I might be hesitant to watch at all. So if you stated sentence #1, I would respond: I would feel embarrassed. If you stated sentence #2, I would respond: I'm not eager to watch. I'm hesitant.

Next, the distinction between "how" in #2 and "what" in #3 is a difference of style. To me, #3 has a more stilted or clinical flavor, perhaps suggesting the studied language of a psychologist. I doubt I've ever actually said that I wonder what someone feels. I would always say that I wonder how someone feels.

Answer (score 0):

Sentences 1 and 3 ask what feelings the person would experience while actually watching the play. The two are essentially equivalent.

Sentence 2 asks whether they want to watch the play or not.

Sentence 4 is wrong, or at least unnatural. You may be mixing "how you'd feel" with "what you'd think."

Comment: Is it natural when ABOUT is followed by NOUN? I read a sentece from dictionary. [We'd like to know What you feel ABOUT abortion.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/feel)

Comment: @StatsCruncher Yes... you can generally trust example sentences from the dictionary :)

Comment: Appropriate discussion is a critical approach of learning. Thank all of you for being here. :)